# What do you have to target to dispel Magic Jar with Dispel Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

[*Magic jar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar) has a duration of "Until dispelled", but [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) targets...

> one object, creature, or magic effect within range

*Magic jar* involves multiple things (a container, yourself, a creature, both souls) but it's unclear to me what the spell is technically "on" (**emphasis** below is mine)

> Any spell of 3rd level or lower **on the target** ends

**What exactly do you have to target to dispel *magic jar* with *dispel magic*?**

Answer (score 8):

## Cast Dispel on the Target of the Magic Jar

The target of *magic jar* is always in the jar or possessing a body.  Wherever that is should be the target for *dispel magic*.

In the description of the spell, the target of the spell is referred to as "you".  Wherever that "you" is, is where the target of *magic jar* is, and should be the target of *dispel magic*.

### Initially in the Container

The "you" is in the container.

> Your body falls into a catatonic state as your soul leaves it and enters the container you used for the spell's material component... The only action **you** can take is to project your soul up to 100 feet **out of the container**, either returning to your living body (and ending the spell) or attempting to possess a humanoids body.

### Possessing a Host Body

The "you" is in the host body.

> While possessing a body, **you** can use your action to **return from the host body to the container** if it is within 100 feet of you, returning the host creature's soul to its body

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yes.  I think that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

## **The effect of dispel magic varies depending on what you target.**

There are 3 things you could conceivably dispel dispel.

1. The casters body
2. A possessed target
3. the soul container

### **The caster**

If you dispel the caster and succeed the spell ends, the container is destroyed and the casters soul attempts to return to their body.

### **A possessed target**

If you dispel a possessed target then the casters soul is ejected and returns to the container if it is able.

### **The container**

It is unclear if the container is a valid target for dispel magic and what the magical effect on it is. It may function as a possessed object or as a creation of the spell itself.

**Is the magical effect its ability to hold souls?**

Since the jar is destroyed when the spell ends it seems the jar is transformed into a new magical object by the spell (a soul container).  If this is the case then when dispelled the container would lose its ability to hold souls and be functionally destroyed. Ending the spell, possibly without the container physically being destroyed because the effect that would have destroyed it was dispelled.

If this was meant to have been the case the spell really should have said that it created a magical  soul container. Making it unambiguous that the container was a magical effect and could be dispelled, destroying it. Instead it is just hinted to be the case.

**Is the magical effect the specific soul inside it?**

Another option is that the jar itself is non magical and that the magical effect is the specific soul in the jar. In  if the jar or the soul is dispelled then which ever soul is in there returns to their body. If it is the casters the spell ends, if it is a victims then they return to their body and the casters soul returns to the container if it is able.

Comment: This is based on the sage advice in this tweet which claims each target of  a spell carries a discrete effect and only the effect on that creature is dispelled when it is targeted by dispel magic. 

https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/1022951482604367875?lang=en